# How to paint a point in a picture box

Tags: visual-studio-2010, picturebox, point

How to paint a point in a picture box in visual studio 2012.
in visual basic 6 it Written:
picture1.pset (x,y) , vb(color)

Comment: Do you want to draw directly with your mouse cursor or rather programmatically and then display the image in the box?

Comment: no i want it for plot.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Graphic object from the picturebox and draw on that:

```
Dim g As Graphics = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics()
g.DrawRectangle(pen, x, y, 1, 1)
```

See [System.Drawing.Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)